# Returning more then one row from DB

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

As you can see in my code below I am using `->row()->$db_field;`.  I somehow need to manipulate this so I can return `$db_field` and `$db_field1`.

What do I need to do to be able to return both rows?

**Code:**

```
if ($query_country->num_rows() > 0)
{
   return $query_country->row()->$db_field;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to call that function for each field, or modify it to grab both values and return an array with both values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
return $query_country->result(); //return query result as object
```

or

```
return $query_country->result_array();//return query result as array
```